# how to call asp.net method from Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi everyone I have a web page that is using Jquery to send the data from a dialog to the asp.net method using $.ajax, but it's always giving me a 404 error Web Page not found.

The Ajax is giving this link to the request "Localhost:1395/Login.aspx/sendEmail" (Obtained using firebug), but send Email is the method that should be called in the Login.aspx page.

This is the JQuery code:

```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'Login.aspx/sendEmail',
       data: '{"strEmail":"' + $('#hplForgotDialog').find('input[id$=txtForgotEmail]').val() + '"}',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json"
   });
```

Any help with this problem would be really apreciated.

Edit: to demonstrate the error a little more I'll add an image depicting the URL error to witch it tries to connect.

[image]

Comment: the method you try to call, is it a webmethod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be, you need to setup routing. You can read about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX

Basically, if I'm right (wich I might not be), your routing doesn't find the correct Actions (or whatever they are called in a non-MVC scenario). In Web Forms, you have to setup custom routes in the Global.asax file, in the Application_Start event handler.

Something like this:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
}
```

With this, you tell the application how to understand URLs, and their parameters. This is the url /Category/param1/param2, everything that matches this pattern, will be directed to the categoriespage.aspx page, what can do whatever it wants with the parameters (call the correct method for example).

Comment: can you elaborate a little more I'm using .NET 3.5 and have never worked with routing....

Comment: I have edited my answer, to provide a little explanation, but you really have to read and understand the article I have linked. Hopefully this helps, I am working with asp.net mvc 4, so I'm not really much of a help, if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Login.aspx/sendEmail",
  data: '{"strEmail":"' + $('#hplForgotDialog').find('input[id$=txtForgotEmail]').val() + '"}',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Your code.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks friend but no good I had already used the success clause but that wasn't the problem,sorry but the thing is it's not doing the request since it thinks the sendEmail is a web page not a method nested within the login.aspx page

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you using asp.net webforms not mvc.
So you have to make the following method in the Login.aspx.cs file (Login class I assume):

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static object sendEmail(string strEmail)
{
  return new { emailSent = true};
}
```

Criterias:
- Method have to be static
- The attributes are required (if you do not wish to return with json, there are other formats)
- The method and the parameters name is from the $.ajax request so if you change you should change that too.